# Cannot import matplotlib.pyplot and makes EOFError

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, eoferror

I am starting the python and I met the module matplotlib.
I am having trouble with importing the `matplotlib.pyplot`.
Actually, I know this is really famous problem, however I cannot fix this problem with any way.

### [Python 2.7: Unable to import matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066496/python-2-7-unable-to-import-matplotlib-pyplot)

For the link above, that was not the same error with mine.

I have EOFError now, makes me annoying. I tried a lot of thing. Such as re-installing matplotlib, install with `conda install matplotlib` not with pip, etc.
Should I have to re-install the anaconda..?

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1429, in <module>
    fontManager = pickle_load(_fmcache)
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 966, in pickle_load
    data = pickle.load(fh)
EOFError: Ran out of input

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1439, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1418, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1053, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 325, in findSystemFonts
    for f in win32InstalledFonts(fontdir):
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 241, in win32InstalledFonts
    direc = os.path.abspath(direc).lower()
  File "C:\Users\water\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 535, in abspath
    path = _getfullpathname(path)
ValueError: _getfullpathname: embedded null character
```

Comment: + I reinstalled all of the python and reinstall matplotlib, but still makes the same error

Comment: I solved it.
by changing
`direc = os.path.abspath(direc).lower()`
to
`direc = direc.split('\0', 1)[0]`